# How do I render a map in Grails view

Tags: grails, groovy

Lets say I have a map like this ( which is returning from a controller)

```
    a= [a:[1,2,3,4],b:[5,6,7,8],c:[9,10]]
   [a] //returning [a] from controller to the view
```

Now in Grails view, how should I render them so that they look something like this in my browser :

```
a
    -- 1
    -- 2 
    -- 3
    -- 4

b
    -- 5
    -- 6
    -- 7
    -- 8
//so on..
```

### Edit:

I did something like this on a particular case of displaying the details(with hint got from the answer given by [Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586767/how-do-i-render-a-map-in-grails-view/8586837#8586837)) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> 
            All Tasks.
        </title>
        <meta name ="layout" content="main" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>All the task</h2>   
        <g:each in="${tasksByDate}" var ="tasks">
            <h4>${tasks.key}</h4>
            <g:each in="${tasksByDate.value}" var="content" >
                <div id = "todayswork"> 
                    ${content}
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </g:each>
            <br />
        </g:each>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I render it in my browser, I'm getting only the heading in my browser. Like this :

```
All the task
//other contents missing. . .
```

And  I'm sure that from the controller `alltasks` the value is passing to the view, with the name `tasksByDate`. As it is printing it on my console like this :

```
[2011-12-19 14:21:35.949:[Belongs to Schedule Finish task A], 2011-12-21 14:21:35.897:[Belongs to Schedule Finish task A], 2011-12-23 14:21:35.907:[Belongs to Schedule Finish task A], 2011-12-19 14:21:36.051:[Belongs to Schedule Finish task A], 2011-12-17 14:21:36.048:[Belongs to Schedule Finish task A]]
```

Here is my controller code :

```
def alltasks = {
    def allTasks = DaySchedule.findAllByTaskIsNotNull()
    def tasksByDate = [:]
    tasksByDate.putAll(
        allTasks.groupBy { 
             it.Todaysdate  
        }
    )
    println tasksByDate
    [tasksByDate]
    }
```

Where I'm making mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, replace the last line of the allTasks action :

```
[tasksByDate]
```

... by ...

```
[tasksByDate : tasksByDate]
```

The return of a controller action (as far as I know) should be a map, not a list. The key is the name of the variable that you will retrieve in the GSP, the value is the contents of that variable.

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#controllers, chapter 6.1.3 Models and Views

Comment: so now how I need to change my view (.gsp) file?

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate over a map elements using `g:each`. The key method of a map element will return the key (a, b, c in your example) and the `value` method will return the associated value (in your case, a list of integers). In turn you can use `g:each` on this list.

Here is what I would do in GSP:

```
<ul>
  <g:each var="mapElement" in="${a}">
    <li>$mapElement.key
      <ul>
        <g:each in="${mapElement.value}" var="number">
          <li>$number</li>
        </g:each>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </g:each>
</ul>
```

Based on your formatting I deduced that you want to present your map as a list of lists, hence the nested `<ul>` elements.

Comment: like this only even I tried... But I'm not getting any output on my screen... i have updated my question with a case